# Spawnar aleatoriamente bola

Tags: c#, unity3d

Boa tardem, estou a realizar um trabalho e é me pedido que faça spawn aleatório de bolas no certo espaço, neste momento as bolas foram colocadas por mim no mapa. Este é o código das bolas:

```
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Coletavel"))
        {
            ParticleSystem explosao = Resources.Load("explosao", typeof(ParticleSystem)) as ParticleSystem;
            explosao = Instantiate(explosao, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            explosao.Play();
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count = count + 1;
            SetCountText();
        }

        if(count == 11){

            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        }

    }
```

Neste pedaço de código coloco se o meu contador for igual a 11 ele muda a cena, contudo eu queria que estas 11 bolas que foram colocadas por mim no mapa fizessem spawn aleatório.

Answer (score -1):

Diogo, irei lhe passar uma simples solução para esta tua indagação.

Dentro do GameObject do Player tu deves ter um código que faça a colisão com o coletável, o que acredito ser exatamente este teu trecho de código acima.

Neste *OnTriggerEnter()* ou *OnCollisionEnter()* (que particularmente não acho necessário fazer cálculo por colisão e sim por um trigger nesta situação), você deve dar um Instantiate no teu Prefab do coletável (ou uma lista de coletáveis), onde irá passar os valores onde este coletável pode instanciar dentro do teu World Space.

Exemplo de código abaixo...

```
void RandomPositionNextColectable() {

    var rangeInX = Random.Range(1, 10);
    var rangeInY = 1;
    var rangeInZ = Random.Range(1, 10);

    Instantiate(prefabCollectable, new Vector3(rangeInX, rangeInY, rangeInZ), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Após esta simples implementação tu podes aprimorar o spawn da mesma, fazendo check se o spawn não está colidindo com um objeto e posicionando o mesmo + um número X de pixeis para direita ou esquerda, por exemplo, mas este controle aconselharia a fazer diretamente no prefab que está sendo instanciado, diferente deste random que ficaria em um Controller ou mesmo no Player.

Answer (score -2):

Diogo, você pode usar a função Random para obter valores aleatórios.

```
var position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-5.0f, 5.0f), Random.Range(-5.0f, 5.0f), 0);
```

e depois use para definir a posição para instanciar as partículas.

```
explosao = Instantiate(explosao, position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Answer (score -2):

Presuma que você que posicionar as 11 bolas em locais aleatórios após trocar de cena.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

Public class BolasPosCena : MonoBehaviour {
    public float Raio;//O raio maximo para os objetos spawnarem
    public Vector3 PontoInicial; //O ponto de onde os objetos seram spawnados
    //A lista de objetos que você que 
    //reposicionar após carregar uma nova cena.
    public List<GameObject> objList;
    void Start() {
        objList = new();
        //Esse método evita que o objetos que essa classe ta
        //seja destruido após carregar uma nova cena.
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode) {
        for(int I = 0; I < objList.Count; I++)
            objList[I].transform.position = PontoInicial * Raio * Random.value;
    }
}
```

Caso for criar novos objetos após carregar uma nova cena e só usar o método  `Instantiate(object)` no `OnSceneLoaded`.
Assim e só um exemplo pra tirar uma base do que fazer.